# Obtener Uri de un contacto teniendo el email

Tags: android

Hola chicos y chicas (por supuesto)

Como hago para desde el correo de un contacto guardado en mi agenda obtener el Uri de este? y entonces desde ahi obtengo el resto de la informacion de este. Esto ultimo ya lo tengo implementado.
Vi un ejemplo en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272558/android-get-contact-photo-from-phone-number de hacerlo con el numero y obtener la foto, pero no se que hacer para que lo haga desde el email

Saludos

Comment: esto te sirve?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740967/how-to-get-contacts-with-email-or-phone-number

Comment: probrare, modificare y te dire luego, igual gracias ese no lo habia visto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto fue lo que hice

```
Cursor cursor= activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + " = '"+mail+"' ", null,null);
String contID = null;
if (cursor !=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    contID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
    cursor.close();
}
```

Luego de tener el id del contacto
con el realizo otro query y obtengo todos los datos de este

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de crear esa función, para obtener el id del contacto a partir del email.

```
public static String getContactByEmail(Context context, String email) {
    if (email == null) return null;

    Uri CONTACTS_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
    };
    final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + " = ?";
    String[] SELECTION_ARG = new String[]{email};

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTACTS_URI, null, SELECTION, SELECTION_ARG, null);
    String contactID = null;
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        contactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
        c.close();
        return contactID;
    } else return null;

}
```

**Su uso**

`String idContact = getContactByEmail(this,"bobesponja@bajo.el.mar");`